# Excel Shortcut to Editbar

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I currently have to do some work in an Excel sheet and as we all know <kbd>Enter</kbd> jumps to the next row (at the current column) and I can start typing.

Until I have to use the arrows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>), which occurs quite often. Then Excel navigates to another cell and I have to use the mouse an click the editingbar at the top (or doubleclick the cell) so I can use the arrows. **Is there any shortcut to jump to the editingbar, so I dont need to use the mouse?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit a cell.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can edit these 300 items without getting angry :)

Comment: The complete list of shortcuts can be found at: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052037811033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the moving of the cursor on enter under Excel Advanced Options.

In Office 2007:

- Ribbon Button
- Excel Options
- Advanced
- After pressing Enter, move selection: Untick the box

In older versions it is under the Edit tab if I remember correctly.